# How to scroll the UITableView which will move horizontally with the elements but stable left and top header?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How to scroll the UITableView which will move horizontally and vertically with the elements but stable left and top header?

Comment: you can scroll it with the touch of your hand